# How to hide "Welcome Back" banner from Game Center login?

Tags: ios, game-center

I've been looking for this information through Apple documents, but could not find the answer. Soon after I launch my Game Center app there is a pop-up that says:

> Welcome back, PlayerName

How can I hide the "Welcome back, playerName" message from Game Center when the player authenticates?

Comment: It's funny, in my game it does not show (the game center works, but no welcome message is displayed), and I was looking how to make it display.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's not. You can't change the behavior of iOS services (which GameCenter is part of) without jailbreaking the device and rewiring them.
And out of curiosity - why do you need that?

Comment: Too bad... The game I'm working on let you register on Open Feint and/or with Game Center, allowing the player to choose its favorite one, in order to only display alerts from this one. It's rather easy for the achievements and automatic for leadeboards, but the two messages prompt in the same time as the player launch the game while logged with both...

Comment: OpenFeint is not a native service, can you hide it's messages? Personally, I wouldn't do OpenFeint unless making a game for Android also.

Comment: I think it must be possible to hide OpenFeint's message, but then if the player has chosen to see only OpenFeint but has subscribed to GameCenter, he will see both the messages...

Comment: And the game is precisely for Android too (and pc, and mac...) :)

Comment: I guess he too thinks the banner is extremely annoying and gets in the way of many games, even if only for three seconds and the user can swipe it up. And I agree; Apple should provide more granularity for the frequency of the banner display.

Comment: Yes, the Game Center Welcome banner can be suppressed programmatically. Code posted below.

Comment: "why do you need that?" - I can't answer on behalf of the OP, but in my opinion the banner is super annoying: It takes significant space from the top of the screen (especially in landscape games), and this is especially detrimental in Tetris-like games where the user has to be aware of what appears on the top of the screen as early as possible. This wouldn't be an issue if the banner appeared as soon as you launch the app (i.e., during the "home screen"); but the log in is quite laggy and the banner typically appears mid-game.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a shorter version for Swift:

```
//Call it right after create this object:
let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
suppressGCBanner(0, originalWindowCount: UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.count)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static func suppressGCBanner(iteration: Int, originalWindowCount: Int) {
    let windows = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows

    if windows.count > originalWindowCount {
        let window = windows[1]

        if window.respondsToSelector("currentBannerViewController") || window.respondsToSelector("bannerSemaphore") {
            print("Found banner, killing it \(iteration)")
            window.hidden = true
            return
        }
    }

    if iteration > 200 {
        print("suppressGCBanner: timeout, bailing")
        return
    }

    runThisAfterDelay(seconds: 0.02, after: {
        suppressGCBanner(iteration + 1, originalWindowCount: originalWindowCount)
    })
}

static func runThisAfterDelay(seconds seconds: Double, after: () -> ()) {
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), after)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to suppress the Game Center Welcome banner programmatically from within your app, at least under iOS 7. My approach is predicated on a few observations:

1. The banner is presented as an additional UIWindow within your UIApplication.
2. This window always seems to appear at index 1. (presuming your app only uses one window.)
3. The banner is 66 pixels high on iPad, 64 on iPhone.
4. The banner contains a 42x42 pixel subview for the Game Center icon.
5. It's known when the banner is likely to appear. (i.e. within a few seconds of creating a GKLocalPlayer object on launch to test authentication.)

So you can simply poll your application's windows repeatedly over these few seconds, waiting for the extra window to appear. (Key-value observing is probably the "correct" way to do this, but I'm lazy.) When the window shows up, test whether it contains a subview hierarchy as described above, which indicates that it's probably the Game Center banner. If it is, set the alpha of the window to 0. That's it.

Here's some code that accomplishes this in my app. I call this method immediately after attempting to authenticate the local player, and it calls itself for a few seconds until it finds (and hides) the banner, or else times out:

```
- (void)suppressGCBanner:(id)object {
    int osVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue];
    if (osVersion != 7) return;  // only tested against iOS 7

    static int iter = 0;    // try for 4 seconds, typically takes about one second for banner to appear
    static int origWindowCount = 0;

    NSArray* windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
    if (origWindowCount == 0) origWindowCount = (int)[windows count];

    BOOL ipad = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
    float bannerHeight = ipad ? 66.0f : 64.0f;  // GC banner has height 66 on iPad, 64 on iPhone

    if ([windows count] > origWindowCount) {
        NSLog(@"suppressGCBanner: found extra window, testing");

        UIWindow* window = [windows objectAtIndex:1]; // in my testing, the GC banner is always at index 1

        for (UIView* view in [window subviews]) {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            NSLog(@"subview size: %f, %f", frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

            if (frame.size.height != bannerHeight) continue;

            for (UIView* subview in [view subviews]) {
                CGRect frame = subview.frame;
                NSLog(@"sub-subview size: %f, %f", frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

                if (frame.size.width == 42.0f && frame.size.height == 42.0f) { // Game Center icon is 42x42
                    NSLog(@"found GameCenter banner: hiding. iter = %i", iter);

                    window.alpha = 0.0f; // make the window invisible!

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (++iter > 200) {
        NSLog(@"suppressGCBanner: timeout, bailing");
        return;
    }

    // ____ otherwise recurse
    [self performSelector:@selector(suppressGCBanner:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.02f];
}
```

Once in a while you'll see a single-pixel line flicker at the top of the screen before the banner is hidden, but in general this method seems to work well enough. Use at your own risk, and enjoy!

Comment: Apologies for the downvote; it was a misclick. Edit your answer and I'll change it. (It won't let me re-click unless the answer is edited.) This code uses no private API's, so Apple has no basis to reject it.

Comment: Apple can reject your app for abusing public APIs too; not just for using private ones. Just saying...

Answer (score 0):

U could log out of Game Center, if that an option for you. Most games are reaction-based and a notification blocking out 15% of the screen for 3 seconds will clearly not be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version adapted to swift3:

```
NameOfYourClass.suppressGCBanner(0, originalWindowCount: UIApplication.shared.windows.count)

static func suppressGCBanner(_ iteration: Int, originalWindowCount: Int) {

    let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows

    if windows.count > originalWindowCount {
        let window = windows[1]
        if window.responds(to: Selector("currentBannerViewController")) || window.responds(to: Selector("bannerSemaphore")) {
            print("Found banner, killing it \(iteration)")
            window.isHidden = true
            return
        }
    }

    if iteration > 200 {
        print("suppressGCBanner: timeout, bailing")
        return
    }

    runThisAfterDelay(seconds: 0.02, after: {
        suppressGCBanner(iteration + 1, originalWindowCount: originalWindowCount)
    })
}

static func runThisAfterDelay(seconds: Double, after: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
        after()
    }
}
```